# Is there a way to generate pdf from html table using tcpdf and all of them are inside in one div in php?

Tags: php, html, json

I have converted my JSON API to HTML TABLE and want this HTML TABLE to be generated into PDF. I use TCPDF and tried all means related to generating pdf using TCPDF. All of these are inside in one div only. I don't know where my codes went wrong and I have just started in PHP so I don't know much about my codes except the HTML.

Here's my code:

```
<?php                               

        $askPriceBeds = '{"status":"success","postcode":"W14 9JH","postcode_type":"full","url":"https://propertydata.co.uk/draw?input=W14+9JH","bedrooms":2,"data":{"points_analysed":20,"radius":"0.09","average":657495,"70pc_range":[ 575000, 725000 ],"80pc_range":[ 550000, 875000 ],"90pc_range":[ 550000, 925000 ],"100pc_range":[ 525000, 950000 ],"raw_data":[ {"price":650000,"lat":"51.48887000","lng":"-0.20776000","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.00" }, {"price":575000,"lat":"51.48884800","lng":"-0.20701200","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.03" }, {"price":615000,"lat":"51.48851000","lng":"-0.20742000","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.03" }, {"price":640000,"lat":"51.48932000","lng":"-0.20804000","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.03" }, {"price":725000,"lat":"51.48843100","lng":"-0.20775400","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.03" }, {"price":699950,"lat":"51.48928000","lng":"-0.20793700","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.03" }, {"price":550000,"lat":"51.48941000","lng":"-0.20832000","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.04" }, {"price":600000,"lat":"51.48813700","lng":"-0.20781600","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.05" }, {"price":925000,"lat":"51.48948300","lng":"-0.20827400","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.05" }, {"price":650000,"lat":"51.48824900","lng":"-0.20669000","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.06" }, {"price":700000,"lat":"51.48941200","lng":"-0.20666900","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.06" }, {"price":625000,"lat":"51.48817000","lng":"-0.20689500","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.06" }, {"price":645000,"lat":"51.48822500","lng":"-0.20872100","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.06" }, {"price":675000,"lat":"51.48877800","lng":"-0.20643200","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.06" }, {"price":525000,"lat":"51.48978800","lng":"-0.20864000","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.07" }, {"price":700000,"lat":"51.48785100","lng":"-0.20757600","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.07" }, {"price":675000,"lat":"51.48819900","lng":"-0.20637900","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.08" }, {"price":875000,"lat":"51.48818700","lng":"-0.20931800","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.08" }, {"price":550000,"lat":"51.48891000","lng":"-0.20955000","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.08" }, {"price":950000,"lat":"51.48808300","lng":"-0.20628500","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.09" } ] },"process_time":"2.08"}';

        $data = json_decode($askPriceBeds, true);

        $raw_data = $data['data']['raw_data'];
        ?>  

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Price</td>
                            <td>Lat</td>
                            <td>Lng</td>
                            <td>Bedrooms</td>
                            <td>Type</td>
                            <td>Distance</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    foreach($raw_data as $raw){
                        echo "<tr>
                            <td>".$raw['price']."</td>
                            <td>".$raw['lat']."</td>
                            <td>".$raw['lng']."</td>
                            <td>".$raw['bedrooms']."</td>
                            <td>".$raw['type']."</td>
                            <td>".$raw['distance']."</td>
                        </tr>";
                        }
                    ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <form method="POST">
                    <input type="submit" name="generate_pdf" value="Generate PDF">
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
            
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['generate_pdf'])){
            
            require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
            
            $tcpdf = new TCPDF(PDG_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
            
            $tcpdf->SetCreator('PDF_CREATOR');
            
            $tcpdf->SetTitle('');
            
            $tcpdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
            
            $tcpdf->setHeaderFont(array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
            
            $tcpdf->setFooterFont(array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
            
            $tcpdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');
            $tcpdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
            
            $tcpdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '5', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
            $tcpdf->setPrintHeader(false);
            $tcpdf->setPrintFooter(false);
            $tcpdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 10);
            $tcpdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);
            $tcpdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');
            
            $html = '<html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Lat</th>
                        <th>Lng</th>
                        <th>Bedrooms</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Distance</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>650000</td>
                        <td>51.48887000</td>
                        <td>-0.20776000</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>flat</td>
                        <td>0.00</td>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>575000</td>
                        <td>51.48884800</td>
                        <td>-0.20701200</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>flat</td>
                        <td>0.03</td>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>615000</td>
                        <td>51.48851000</td>
                        <td>-0.20742000</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>flat</td>
                        <td>0.03</td>
                    <tr>
                </table>
            </body>
            </html>';
            
            $tcpdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);
            $tcpdf->lastPage();
            $tcpdf->Output("datareport.pdf", 'I');
        }
        ?>
```

I wonder if the mistake here is that one PHP file is not enough to generate the pdf?

Comment: The first issue I see is, that you are outputting your HTML twice. Once to the browser and then, again, to the PDF. When you call `Output`, the browser will think that the data is part of the above HTML.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium - So should I separate one of them on another PHP file? Is there no way to put them in one div?

Comment: There is a rather easy way, but please explain what you mean by `one div`.

Comment: By one div, I mean all of the codes I put above are all inside in a `<div>` and would still work from JSON > HTML > PDF.

Comment: Have you tried the alteration I suggested below and see if it does what you want it to do? If you want to embed the resulting PDF in the above page, I think we'll need some sort of additional container.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it helps:

```
<?php                               
    if (!isset($_POST['generate_pdf']))
    { 
        //Your JSON code
    ?>
        //Your HTML code
<?php
    }
    else
    {
        //Your PDF code
    }
?>
```

Your code sends the HTML before you check, whether you actually want the PDF to be output. This will result in the actual PDF file to be treated as part of the HTML instead of as a standalone document.

A common error message that hints at this reads (something like): `Cannot send headers. Headers have already been sent.`

Comment: I tried the alteration, but it didn't read the HTML Code. It might be the HTML is inside the PHP tag.

Comment: Yes, quite so. I amended the answer to include the corresponding tags.

Comment: I tried again but still didn't work.

Comment: 'Doesn't work' is a very bad error description. What does it do? What do you expect it to do? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Got it. Sorry for the bad description. How do I check the message error? 
Sorry for not explaining much about this but the codes I'm writing are on WordPress but still this is the same on the local right? So what error I got is "There has been a critical error on this website."

Comment: That error usually tells you to go to the console level and look at the log of your webserver for more details. (`/var/log/apache2/error.log` for most Linux systems.) In general, means, there is a syntax error somewhere in your code, like a brace you did not close or something the likes.